# How to do synchronous calling of HttpClient in Blazor

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I want to call an API synchronously in Blazor, But it is not working. Is there a way call API synchronously. Please find the below code.

**Currently using asynchronous call as mentioned below:**

```cs
    if(HttpClient == null)
    {
        HttpClient = new HttpClient();
        HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", userContext.Token);
    }
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
    HttpContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    
    var httpResponse = await HttpClient.PostAsync(api, content);
    
    httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    
    var response = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var parsedResult = JObject.Parse(response);
    return parsedResult["returnObj"].ToString();
```

**Tried below way but Blazor is not supporting:**

```cs
    string response;
    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create($"{userContext.ServerAddress}/Erp.BO.ConfigurationRuntimeSvc/{apiName}");
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + userContext.Token);
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    
    // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
    
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Flush();
    }
    
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    
    var parsedResult = JObject.Parse(response);
    return parsedResult["returnObj"].ToString();
```

Please provide a solution

Answer (score 1):

Don´t know if that helps you, but a similar question was asked some time ago on Github:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/16217

Edit:

Summary of the article:

Basically you shouldn´t do a synchronous Http call.
Preferable option: `var result = await HttpClient.GetJsonAsync<T>(myUrl);`

This is the solution if you really want to do it synchronish:

> You can run asynchronous operations before starting the renderer if you want to. For example,
>
> ```cs
>     static void Main(string[] args)
>     {
>     Task.Run(async () =>
>     {
>         var serviceProvider = new BrowserServiceProvider(services =>
>         {
>             // Add any custom services here
>         });
>
>         // First run an async HTTP request
>         var httpClient = serviceProvider.GetService<HttpClient>();
>         var data = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("/api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts");
>         Console.WriteLine("Fetched data: " + data);
>
>         // Now the request is completed, start rendering the UI
>         new BrowserRenderer(serviceProvider).AddComponent<App>("app");
>     });
>     }
> ```
>
> This is the preferred solution, rather than attempting to block the UI
> thread (which browsers don't allow - they'll say the tab has crashed
> if you're blocking the UI thread).